# How to use jquery bubble popup for more than one content

Tags: php, jquery

Hello i need to load an image from an database and the popup should be there when i keep the mouse over the images...i used http://www.vegabit.com/jquery_bubble_popup/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dummy1').SetBubblePopup({
        innerHtml: '<p>You can set any HTML tag<br />inside this popup!<br /><a href="#">this is a link</a></p>'
    });
 });
```

how can i use this for some 10 images from database using php??

Answer (score 1):

Give each image a unique ID and give them the CSS class bubblepopup, then use this code.

```
$('.bubblepopup').SetBubblePopup({
    innerHtml: '<p>You can set any HTML tag<br />inside this popup!<br /><a href="#">this is a link</a></p>'
});
```

Comment: What text would change and where would you get that info from?

Comment: database info such name of that image

Comment: You can get the name many ways, maybe use the title attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue recently, but I was able to solve it.  Each element that I need to add a popup to is given a class of "bubbler" just so I can keep track of things.  I store the HTML content for each popup inside a title attribute for the element.

For example:

```
<a href="" title="This is a link" class="bubbler">text</a>
<span id="span_1" title="This is a span<br />with two lines" class="bubbler>text</span>
<input type="text" class="bubbler" title="Please enter a valid email" />
```

Then you do a simple select based on the class, but use each element's title attribute to set the innerHTML:

```
$('.bubbler').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.CreateBubblePopup({
        position: 'top',
        align: 'center',
        innerHtml: $this.attr('title'),
        innerHtmlStyle: {
            color: '#ffffff',
            'text-align': 'center'
        },
        themeName: 'all-blue',
        themePath: 'images/jquerybubblepopup-theme'
    });
});
```

This will loop through the entire collection of bubble-ready elements, create bubble popups, and assign the innerHTML to be whatever text you assigned to the title attribute.  Just make sure your PHP functions are setting the title when they render the page, and you should be fine.